# SOQL query to JOIN all Product2s with their corresponding PricebookEntry in the standard price book

Tags: soql, rest-api

I'm trying to send some SOQL in the REST API, in order to JOIN all entries from `Product2` with their `UnitPrice` value in the corresponding `PricebookEntry` in the standard price book.

Either a LEFT JOIN or INNER JOIN could possibly work for my scenario. – Here's my naive attempt:

```
SELECT p.Id, 
       p.Description, 
       p.IsActive, 
       p.Name, 
       p.ProductCode, 
       (SELECT Product2Id, 
               UnitPrice 
        FROM   PricebookEntry pe) 
FROM   Product2 p 
WHERE  pe.Product2Id =: p.Id
```

The above query fails with:

```
'bind variables only allowed in Apex code'
```

What's the part that I'm missing? Is this really possible only in Apex?

Comment: You forgot the = : in the where clause before the p.Id .. I used to do that too ! So you want to add an extra : before p.Id

Comment: +1 Thank you, Simon. That was a typo which I've now fixed. However I'm still getting the same error...

Comment: @NikosBaxevanis: check my answer.

Comment: Ah.. make sure to use the relationship API name for the table in the Subselect, so it should be FROM PricebookEntries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no concept of INNER JOIN or OUTER JOIN.
Instead, there are SEMI JOIN and ANTI JOIN in SOQL.

The query you are looking for is this one:

```
SELECT p.Id, 
       p.Description, 
       p.IsActive, 
       p.Name, 
       p.ProductCode, 
       (SELECT Product2Id, 
               UnitPrice 
        FROM   PricebookEntries) 
FROM   Product2 p
```

Comment: Hmm... However, when I execute this in Apex Explorer, I still see only the fields from the `Product2` table. I don't see `UnitPrice` anywhere in the results.

Comment: @NikosBaxevanis You need to use a tool that supports it. The Developer Console and the Data Loader both don't support it. Try using the [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/).

Comment: But then, will I be able to use that query through the Salesforce REST API?

Comment: @NikosBaxevanis Certainly. Try it out in the REST Explorer in the Workbench.